# jsf 2.1 file upload with Servlet Container 2.5

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2

I'm try to upload Excel files in JSF2.1. I'm using JDK1.5 and tomcat6 server. How to implement the file upload? I have tried so many examples from online. But still i can't get any improvement. Please anyone give me idea or example code to JSF 2.1 file upload on Tomcat6

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with a great solution from BalusC:
http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html ? 
I know this solution is related to Servlet 3.0 and you need one for Servlet 2.5, but, did you try it regardless?

Comment: Thank you for reply, Yes i was tried BalusC, but it's not working with Servlet container 2.5